# jQuery not picking up AJAX rerendering of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a webpage with a table of contents of links like this:

```
<div class="tableOfContents">
   <a href="#">A-D</a>
   <a href="#">E-K</a>
   <a href="#">L-P</a>
   <!-- etc... -->
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

When those links are clicked, #content is populated with associated different values. I'm trying to use jQuery (via web inspector console) to click through through the links and scrape whatever's in #content. However, although the "click" event trigger works when I call it by itself in the console, this script isn't working as expected: it scrapes the same content (A-D's contents) in each iteration.

```
$(".tableOfContents a").on("click", function() {
    var content = $("#content").text();
    // scrape content...
});

var list = $(".tableOfContents").find('a'); 

for (j=0; j < list.length; j++) {
    list.get(j).click();
}
```

I end up with the scrape for A-D's content in each iteration, although by the time the script finishes running we've clicked through and have landed on the last page. Any thoughts on what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Well the code looks like it's always looking at the same `<div>`, the one with the id "content". (Your ids must be unique, in case that's not clear.)

Comment: Just wondering, does your actual code use `<!-- etc... ->` or is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I ambiguated the question so there's no real <!-- etc.. --> in there. Pointy, that should be var content = $("#content").text();

Comment: I was able to run the code and the click events work. Yet, it's unclear what you want to do with #content, which is an empty div.

Comment: Robert, sorry, I ambiguated the question for privacy concerns--let's say for the purposes of the question I just want to log $("#content").text() to console.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at your #content before it is actually updated by another click handler possibly involving an AJAX call? Why not just poll #content for changes?

Comment: @idrarig how would you propose polling #content for changes? I think what you described is what's going wrong

Comment: @user1436111 Well if performance is not a problem I would just set an interval and wait for $('#content').text() to change value, after that, I would go on and click the next anchor and go back to polling.

Comment: idrarig makes a good point. Yet, it's difficult to suggest a solution without knowing how content is loaded.

Comment: @Robert I think he went back to coding :-).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Thank you @idrarig & @Robert! Also, i'm not a he. :)